# Export map with legend using OpenLayers 6

Tags: openlayers, export, legend, pdf

I would like to export a map with a legend in the same PDF using OpenLayers 6.
I searched in the OpenLayers documentation but got a map without a legend.
How can I do this?

Comment: Please [Edit] the Question to contain the relevant block of code.

Answer (score 1):

jsPDF allows you to add multiple images to the PDF [https://rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/module-addImage.html#~addImage](https://rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/module-addImage.html#%7EaddImage) so if you you combine the Export PDF and WMS GetLegendGraphic examples the only extra code that would be needed after adding the map canvas is

```
  var img = document.getElementById("legend");
  pdf.addImage(
    img,
    "JPEG",
    0,
    dim[1] - img.height,
    img.width,
    img.height
  );
```

(this would place the legend in the bottom left corner)

https://codesandbox.io/s/morning-sky-4gsv8?file=/main.js

Comment: first thank you for your answer , i checked this web site "https://codesandbox.io/s/morning-sky-4gsv8?file=/main.js" ,i found that we don't have the same daclaration for the legend , i used this one "https://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/examples/legend/map.control.legends.html"

Comment: in my case i used " ol.control. Legend " to create my legend , so how can i add this  legend to my pdf ??????????????

Comment: To export a control you could use dom-to-image-more as in https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/print-to-scale.html and replace `ol-scale` in `exportOptions` with `ol-legend`

Comment: THANK YOU ,it's working ,now  i want to do the same thing with "downoald png " , how can i do it ?