# QGIS2web Export open layers map as PDF, PNG or JPEG

Tags: javascript, openlayers, qgis2web, angular

I want to have an option to export my map as the PDF

I would like to use the example from here:

https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/export-pdf.html

but it doesn't work unfortunately. All the issues have been described here:

https://github.com/tomchadwin/qgis2web/issues/934

it looks like I need to set the server for this.

Here is also the solution:

https://talk.observablehq.com/t/save-a-map-openlayers/2598

which I don't really understand

I think everything is related to the issue here:

https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/10593

In all the cases I can't use the stuff

```
 import 'ol/ol.css';
 import Map from 'ol/Map';
```

and so on, because I am getting an error:

because the console says:

**Cannot use import statement outside a module**

related to this query:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58211880/uncaught-syntaxerror-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module-when-import

https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/issues/922

https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/15957

I found another hint here:

[Export map with legend using OpenLayers 6](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/374578/export-map-with-legend-using-openlayers-6)

but seems to be not suitable for my case

In the other side, the code presented here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64823306/save-openlayers-map-as-pdf

returns the blank PDF document.

[image]

The final question is - does anyone know how to export map from Openlayers to PDF, PNG or JPEG without any `import` operator and additional server requirements?

I could need something like this:

https://codepen.io/barbalex/pen/raagKq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to use imports, you can use the full build syntax in your code instead, where  https://openlayers.org/en/latest/doc/quickstart.html is equivalent to https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/simple.html

So the Export PDF example becomes:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.4.3/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
    <style>
      .map {
        width: 100%;
        height:400px;
      }
      .map {
        max-width: 566px;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.4.3/build/ol.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.5.3/jspdf.min.js"></script>
    <title>Export PDF example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="row-fluid">
      <div class="span12">
        <div id="map" class="map"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <form class="form">
      <label>Page size </label>
      <select id="format">
        <option value="a0">A0 (slow)</option>
        <option value="a1">A1</option>
        <option value="a2">A2</option>
        <option value="a3">A3</option>
        <option value="a4" selected>A4</option>
        <option value="a5">A5 (fast)</option>
      </select>
      <label>Resolution </label>
      <select id="resolution">
        <option value="72">72 dpi (fast)</option>
        <option value="150">150 dpi</option>
        <option value="300">300 dpi (slow)</option>
      </select>
    </form>
    <button id="export-pdf">Export PDF</button>
<script>

var raster = new ol.layer.Tile({
  source: new ol.source.XYZ({
    url: 'https://{a-c}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
    crossOrigin: 'anonymous'
  }),
});

var format = new ol.format.WKT();
var feature = format.readFeature(
  'POLYGON((10.689697265625 -25.0927734375, 34.595947265625 ' +
    '-20.1708984375, 38.814697265625 -35.6396484375, 13.502197265625 ' +
    '-39.1552734375, 10.689697265625 -25.0927734375))'
);
feature.getGeometry().transform('EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');

var vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: new ol.source.Vector({
    features: [feature],
  }),
  opacity: 0.5,
});

var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [raster, vector],
  target: 'map',
  view: new ol.View({
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 2,
  }),
});

var dims = {
  a0: [1189, 841],
  a1: [841, 594],
  a2: [594, 420],
  a3: [420, 297],
  a4: [297, 210],
  a5: [210, 148],
};

var exportButton = document.getElementById('export-pdf');

exportButton.addEventListener(
  'click',
  function () {
    exportButton.disabled = true;
    document.body.style.cursor = 'progress';

    var format = document.getElementById('format').value;
    var resolution = document.getElementById('resolution').value;
    var dim = dims[format];
    var width = Math.round((dim[0] * resolution) / 25.4);
    var height = Math.round((dim[1] * resolution) / 25.4);
    var size = map.getSize();
    var viewResolution = map.getView().getResolution();

    map.once('rendercomplete', function () {
      var mapCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
      mapCanvas.width = width;
      mapCanvas.height = height;
      var mapContext = mapCanvas.getContext('2d');
      Array.prototype.forEach.call(
        document.querySelectorAll('.ol-layer canvas'),
        function (canvas) {
          if (canvas.width > 0) {
            var opacity = canvas.parentNode.style.opacity;
            mapContext.globalAlpha = opacity === '' ? 1 : Number(opacity);
            var transform = canvas.style.transform;
            // Get the transform parameters from the style's transform matrix
            var matrix = transform
              .match(/^matrix\(([^\(]*)\)$/)[1]
              .split(',')
              .map(Number);
            // Apply the transform to the export map context
            CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.setTransform.apply(
              mapContext,
              matrix
            );
            mapContext.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0);
          }
        }
      );
      var pdf = new jsPDF('landscape', undefined, format);
      pdf.addImage(
        mapCanvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg'),
        'JPEG',
        0,
        0,
        dim[0],
        dim[1]
      );
      pdf.save('map.pdf');
      // Reset original map size
      map.setSize(size);
      map.getView().setResolution(viewResolution);
      exportButton.disabled = false;
      document.body.style.cursor = 'auto';
    });

    // Set print size
    var printSize = [width, height];
    map.setSize(printSize);
    var scaling = Math.min(width / size[0], height / size[1]);
    map.getView().setResolution(viewResolution / scaling);
  },
  false
);

   </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Note I have changed OSM to XYZ, if you are not using an OpenLayers source such as OSM which defaults to crossOrigin **it is important to specify the crossOrigin option** as tainted canvas cannot be exported.